# Scale only 2 axis in a 3d matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the case where a maplotlib 3d plot have 2 axis that represents the same kind of measurement (for example a length) and another one of a different kind (for example time). I would like to scale only 2 axis (the ones representing the length) but not the other one.
In a 2d plot I would do this with `ax.axis("equal")`, but this command scales all the axis.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Axes3D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.html) class has a [`set_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_aspect.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_aspect) method, which allows you to set the aspect ratio of any pair of axes to equal, e.g.:

```
ax.set_apect("equalxy")
```

to set the x-y axes to have equal aspect ratios, but leaving the z-axis scale unchanged.